# add image slider in home page using drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I want to add image slider in home page which is user editable and I am using `Drupal7` for this.
I have used `view_slideshow` module and then created  new content type as `featured_slider` and created view and added custom region in  `.info` file and then configured the block.
But still I am not getting Image slider on homepage.

Is that possible to put slider in header region.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the region to render in your template files? if not, make sure to print it where you want it to show up inside `page.tpl.php` or any other template file at your theme templates folder as follows: `print render($page['name_of_your_region']);`

Comment: Yes ,still not getting result